# What is "third parties reading habits"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english

The headline is:

> Degrowth, third parties and my reading habits: your questions, answered

Could *third parties reading habits* mean the habits of reading what someone else is reading, for example being influenced by them for reading what they're reading or inspired by them to read what they're reading? If it's so, I imagine the *degrowth* part means to wane doing so.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because the headline says "third parties **and my** reading habits", which are two separate things, but you are asking about "third parties reading habits".  Are you just asking what "third parties reading habits" would mean if that were what the headline said?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @stangson, I truly believed that 'third parties and my reading habits' were all about reading If its not, what third party means in that context?

Comment: It is relatively common to refer to two or more unrelated subjects in the same headline or title. One example of this is the 1989 film "Sex, lies and videotape".  That's how I read this headline.

Comment: FWIW, "third parties reading habits" doesn't make any sense in the first place - you'd need a possessive apostrophe somewhere, either "third party's reading habits" or "third parties' reading habits", to indicate the reading habits of one or multiple third parties.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the title of your question does not match the quote. There's a big difference between "third parties reading habits" and "third parties and my reading habits".

The headline you quote indicates that the article will answer your questions about three things: "degrowth", "third parties", and "my reading habits". Apparently this is a headline from an article in the New York Times, but I don't have a subscription so I can't read it. (And sorry, but I'm not going to subscribe to this web site just to help me answer this question.) In any case, the writer says that he is answering questions from readers. So it seems he got questions from readers on these three subjects. There's no reason (without reading the article) to suppose that they are related.

"Degrowth" is a political movement that says that a growing economy is a bad thing. We should essentially freeze the economy at the present level of wealth in order to limit pollution and preserve resources. People who are presently poor should remain poor so that there is enough wealth left to maintain the lifestyle of the rich.

"Third parties" is probably referring to political third parties. In the United States, we have two major political parties: The Democrats and the Republicans. Any other political party is routinely referred to as a "third party".

"Third parties" can also refer to people not directly involved in some situation. Like, "My wife and I are having an argument. Maybe we need an independent third party who could be objective."

Without reading the article, I don't know which use of "third parties" he has in mind.

"My reading habits" means "the things I commonly read". Like, "My reading habits mostly include science fiction and romance novels."